# existentional types scala scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

In scalaz library there is a definition of `compose` function in `Functor`:

```
def compose[G[_]](implicit G0: Functor[G]): Functor[λ[α => F[G[α]]]] =
```

What is this `λ` doing here and how to interpret that?

It would make sense for me to be short version of `({type λ[α] = F[G[α]]})#λ`

But when I try to just copy this snipet from scalaz to my code I always get `not found: type`.

Where is this magic coming from :(

Comment: could you provide a link to the `compose` function definition, please?

Comment: The `λ` is coming from the [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector/) compiler plugin.

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was looking for